# Python function to get a list of subclasses of a given class from searching through all pages in a directory

Tags: python, subclass

I need a function that would get a list of all the files that end in ".py" in a given directory and then, for each file, find out if there are subclasses of a given class in that file. If there are, then add an instance of the class to a list. If not, then continue, then return the list when done. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: @Asad Please excuse my confusing language. >_< I'd like to know how this could be done, not if it could be done. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: It's possible you don't need to do this manually because new-style classes keep of their immediate subclasses. See [`__subclasses__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__subclasses__#class.__subclasses__).

Comment: @martineau I read somewhere that __subclasses__ only returns direct inheritors, or inheritors in the same file, which is a problem because the inheritors will be all over the place.

Comment: If you just import all the modules then check the `__subsclasses__` attribute of the base class, it should have all that were defined in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module. by `load_module` or `load_source` you can dynamically load `.py` file into an module object. use `dir` to see what is in that module and you also have `issubclass` function to check whether there is an inheritance between two class.